# D compiler profiling

Tags: profiling, d

How to figure out which part of my d code takes long time to compile?

I tried to use valgrind, but the the method names were not very insightful. 87% of time was spent in `<cycle 7>`, 40% of the time in `_D4ddmd5lexer5Lexer4scanMFPS4ddmd6tokens5TokenZv`

I'm looking for something like this: 40% of the time was spent on `xy.d`, out of that 80% of the time took compiling various instantiations of template `xyz` and a reason is because it used `memcpy` 99% of the time.

I'm interested profiling both DMD and LDC.

Comment: What language is the D compiler written in? Can you run a debug version of the D compiler under GDB? If you can, pause it and look through the compiler's data structure and see what it's working on. Do this a few times. What it's working on the most will be apparent. You don't need anything like exact measurements.

Comment: I don't know (yet) how to hook it up to GDB, and how to get a debug version of the compilers, but I'll try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the D compiler front end is written in D, profiling using conventional tools will be rather hard compared to something like C++. I have had some success using tools like gdb and valgrind on Linux and tools like VisualD on Windows, Mac users are kind of SOL.

You have five other options:

1. Stop trying to find the specific function in the compiler and turn to common knowledge about the problem (see below)
2. Use a tool like https://github.com/CyberShadow/DBuildStat. It doesn't give you the exact answer you're asking about, but if you're trying to get a large project to compile faster it's better than nothing.
3. Use the `-v` flag to try and see which parts of your program take a while. Granted, this is a very brute force approach and can take you a while.
4. Modify the makefile the DMD front-end to use the `-profile` switch. Every time you run DMD you will get a profile file with a lot of information. Granted, I don't think this has ever been tried. Your milage may vary.
5. Try to ask the LDC team about this on their Github issues page. IIRC they made a patched version for profiling that they used for the Weka.io codebase.

When I say turn to common knowledge, I mean to say that your slow compilation is likely due to a few common problems. For example, when an SQL query is taking too long, my first reaction is not to try to profile the MySQL server code. Here are a couple of the most common issues

1. CTFE, while it speeds up your runtime, is **slow**. Especially if your doing recursive templates like `allSatisfy` or your using functions like `ctRegex`. If you're doing heavy CTFE and you want faster compiles at the price of possible slower code, consider switching them to run time calls.
2. DMD doesn't (yet) ignore symbols which aren't used in your program, meaning if you import a module, code-gen will happen for all of the functions in the module. This is true even for selective imports. If you don't use them the linker will prune the functions from the resulting executable, but the compiler still took time to compile them. Avoid imports like `import std.algorithm;` or `import std.range;`. Instead use package specific imports like `import std.algorithm.iteration : map;`.